# "%m %" operator with mapply

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to use mapply to add months to the current dates in columns a and b of my dataframe.  Here is the code to create a sample data frame:

```
library(lubridate)
a <- as.Date(c("2012-01-11","2012-06-30","2012-04-18"))
b <- as.Date(c("2013-04-21","2012-03-22","2012-05-01"))
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I can use `mapply("+",df, c(30,30))` to add 30 days to both columns of dates.  However, when I try to use the command `mapply("%m+%",df, months(1:2))` I get the error message:

> Error in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE) :    no slot of
>   name "group" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"

Is it possible to use mapply with the %m+% operator?

Comment: What package is the operator `%m+%` and the function `months` in? I don't think it's in `base`. Is it `lubridate`?

Comment: 6 different packages (none of them lubridate) show up with `library(sos); findFn"%m+%")`.

Comment: Yes, `%m+%` is from the lubridate package.

Comment: I can verify, despite `sos` not finding it, `%m+%` is indeed part of the [lubridate package](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/R/ops-%25m%2B%25.r). I've never come to grips with the methods setting procedure for S4 methods, but the issue appears to be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my S4 ignorant eyes, this appears to be an issue with the lubridate package and the way the  `%m+%` method is constructed.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/R/ops-%25m%2B%25.r),

It appears that the unexported function `.quick_month_add` will do what you want

```
 mapply(lubridate:::.quick_month_add,df,months(1:2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
$a
[1] "2012-01-11" "2012-06-30" "2012-04-18"

$b
[1] "2013-04-21" "2012-03-22" "2012-05-01"
```

note that `SIMPLIFY` must be set to `FALSE` otherwise you will get numeric matrix as the Date class is stripped when simplifying to a matrix.

Or, `Map(lubridate:::.quick_month_add,df,months(1:2))`

Comment: A bit of a playing around with a custom `Map2` function, https://gist.github.com/hadley/4758366, suggests that it's because we haven't implemented a `[[` method for periods.

Comment: FYI I prefer using `Map` to `mapply` because it defaults to `simplify = FALSE`

Comment: I think it should be `Map(lubridate:::.quick_month_add,df,1:2)` rather than `Map(lubridate:::.quick_month_add,df,months(1:2))`