# Calendar date arithmetic in R

Tags: r, datetime

Is there a way in R to do calendar arithmetic, e.g.

```
> as.Date('2014-03-30') - months(1)
[1] 2014-02-28
```

except in reality there's no such `months` function. This can be done with awareness of leap years and daylight savings time in SQL and Java, but I can't find a way to do it in R. I thought I'd get clever and use `seq` but no:

```
> seq(as.POSIXct('2014-03-30', tz='UTC'), by = '-1 months', length=2)[2]
[1] "2014-03-02 UTC"
```

Comment: check out the lubridate package

Comment: @timriffe lubridate doesn't work either. In my example you get `NA`. Supposedly I could use `%m-%` but [that is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14819362/712765).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way using [RcppBDT](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.bdt.html) which wraps 
(parts of) [Boost Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time.html) for use by R:

```
R> library(RcppBDT)
R> dt <- new(bdtDt, 2014, 3, 30)
R> dt
[1] "2014-03-30"
R> dt$addMonths(-1)
R> dt
[1] "2014-02-28"
R>
```

Comment: Should `bdtDt` be `bdtDate`? I'm getting errors over here otherwise. Actually I don't have `addMonths` either, but I have `addDays`.

Comment: It was a copy and paste from my R session. Make sure run the recent 0.2.3 version.  Similar / related code is also in `demo/RcppBDTdd.R`. And just for you I just re-ran it on a fresh session on another machine.

Comment: I'm wasting your time it appears - that'll teach me for not updating.

Answer (score -1):

This is too long for an organized comment, but `months` *is* a function, and using `as.POSIXlt` (as opposed to ct) can allow for easy extraction of date attributes.

```
test <- as.POSIXlt('2014-03-30', tz='UTC')
attributes(test)$names
test$mon
months(test)
```

Given that `test$mon` returns a numeric value, it would be easy to perform arithmetic on the months.  However, subtracting 1 month from January just gives you -1 (Jan is 0), and redefining `test$mon <- test$mon - 1` doesn't seem to be of much help.

Nonetheless, depending on your application, the above information may still be useful.

Comment: That's what the `seq` solution actually does. If you do `xx<-as.POSIXlt('2014-03-30'); xx$mon<-xx$mon-1; xx; you get `"2014-03-02"`. It tries to go to Feb-30 which doesn't exit. Since that would in theory be two days after Feb 28, it goes to Mar 2.